# How to alert users that they have a survey / webform to complete

Tags: 7, webforms

Using D7 with the latest version of webform.  We have created several surveys and all is working fine, but a question came up in a meeting, is there an easier/automated way of sending emails to the specific users that need to complete the survey.  What we do now, is create the survey, save, then go into our email client and send out a note that a survey is ready for you to complete at whatever url.

We would like to click a button "send survey url to:" and then add the email address of the user who needs to be alerted of the availability of the survey.  They would jsut click the link and be taken to the the survey.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this goal using [Views Send](https://drupal.org/project/views_send) module.

> - Create a view and add at least one column containing e-mail    addresses.
> - [Optional] Expose Views filters to let the user easily build list of    recipients using UI.
> - Add the "Global: Send E-mail" field to your view. This field provides    the checkboxes that allow the user to select multiple
>   rows.
> - Create a "Page" (or "Block") display.
> - Save the view, load the page, use exposed filters to build the list,    select all or some rows and then click the "Send e-mail"
>   button.
> - Fill the message form to configure the e-mail. Use tokens to    personalize your e-mail. The module provide also row-based tokens,
>   taken from the current row of the view. For example, if the view has
>   a column with the key users_name (the user name) you can use this
>   replacement token [views-send-users_name].
> - Preview and send the mail.

For more information go through the module documentation.

Comment: Humm, this is really interesting.  I have not heard of views send.  I will give it a try.  Thank you for the suggestions.